# Firebase custom domain, other hosting provider

Tags: firebase, dns, hosting

So firebase seems cool! i would love to build my angular webapp and use firebase to host it. Pushing it to firebase with my terminal seems like a dream.

I bought my custom domain on Siteground.com
When starting out with firebase it asked me to change the DNS records on siteground to direct my custom domain to firebase.
Which i did and seems to be working correctly.

My question now is, do i still need my siteground.com hosting? Maybe a newb qeustion.
But i am seriously confused now.
Cause when i want to buy a domain mostly it comes together with a hosting plan like on siteground. I dont see an option on firebase to get custom domains with firebase hosting, thats why i am wondering how this all works together.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you only need a domian, and firebase is doing your hosting. if your host provider don't have such plan prefer [Google Domains](https://domains.google/intl/en_in/#/) which is still on beta, but there is a good chance to add it to firebase services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are typically two services that, together, make up "web hosting".

The first is a **DNS Provider**. Your DNS provider is what tells computers that try to load `yourdomain.com` that it needs to talk to a server at IP address `X.X.X.X`.

The second is a **Web Host** (e.g. Firebase Hosting). This is what actually serves up the content for your website from an IP address.

You'll need both for your domain to work correctly, but many providers offer both services together. Firebase Hosting is a web host, but it is *not* a DNS provider. Typically your domain registrar is also your DNS provider and provides DNS configuration for free when you purchase a domain.

Hope that helps!

Comment: He Michael, Yes that helps! thanks a lot for your clear explanation. I learned something new here. Now i understand that firebase is not a DNS provider. And my DNS provider is where i bought the domain. I probably do not need their hosting service anymore when i use firebase. But they will be my DNS provider for this domain. Thanks.